# Why does getw return -1 when trying to read a character?

Tags: c

I hoped I will see the result 65 since 65 is the ASCII value of A.

Why am I getting -1 instead?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("first.txt","w");
    putc('A',fp);
    fclose(fp);
    fp=fopen("first.txt","r");
    int x=getw(fp);
    printf("%d\n",x);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How did you even hear about `getw`? This suggests something very very wrong with whatever material you're learning from...

Answer (score 16):

You are writing one byte to the file, but then try to read `sizeof(int)` bytes back from it. `getw()` returns `EOF` because of that, and the value of `EOF` is -1.

For this reason, when using `getw()` you should examine the file handle using `ferror()` to be able to tell whether the value `getw()` returned is the value read from the file or an error code.

Or better yet, use `fread()` to read from files. `getw()` is an old function that's there for compatibility with old code. Or use `getc()` or `fgetc()` instead, which always return an `unsigned char` cast to an `int` and thus `EOF` can be easily distinguished:

```
int x = getc(fp);
if (x == EOF) {
    fputs("Error reading from file.\n", stderr);
} else {
    printf("%d\n",x);
}
```

Comment: Would using getc and storing the value in a char fix this?

Comment: @jackw11111 getc yes, char no. getc returns an int (to accommodate EOF).

Answer (score 6):

Oh, I see you have a problem right there with "w" just change "w" to "c" and smile. Actually, you're on the right track. Just change getw() to getc().

The output is -1 because you are using getw() function to read a .txt file that contains a char whereas, getw() function reads an integer from file. So the right function to use is getc() function because you have a char in your .txt file. getc() function reads character from file.

Copy and paste even faster:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("first.txt","w");
    putc('A',fp);
    fclose(fp);
    fp=fopen("first.txt","r");
    int x=getc(fp);
    printf("%d\n",x);

    return 0;
}
```

This would output 65.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting `-1` because `getw()` reads the next word from the stream (the size of a word is the size of an `int` and may vary from machine to machine) but in you case, when it try to read word from file it encounters `EOF` and the end-of-file indicator for the stream is set and `getw()` returns `EOF`. Note that `EOF` is a macro which expands to an integer constant expression with type `int` and an implementation dependent negative value but is very commonly `-1`.

You should use `putw()` to write the file, if you want to use `getw()` to read the file.

To show you the difference in file when using `putc()` and `putw()` to write the file:

When using `putc()`:

```
putc('A',fp);
```

check the size of file:

```
# ls -lh first.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 <owner>  <group>     1B May 11 18:02 first.txt
                                   ^
                                   |
                                size: 1 byte
```

When using `putw()`:

```
putw('A', fp);   // the first parameter type of putw() is int and the character will implicitly promoted to int
```

check the size of file:

```
# ls -lh first.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 <owner>  <group>     4B May 11 18:00 first.txt
                                   ^
                                   |
                                size: 4 bytes
```

If using `putw()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("first.txt", "w");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Failed to open file for write");
        return -1;
    }

    putw('A', fp); // add the error handling for putw()
    fclose(fp);

    fp = fopen("first.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Failed to open file for read");
        return -1;
    }

    int x = getw(fp);

    if (feof(fp)) {
        printf ("End of file reached\n");
    }
    else if (ferror(fp)) {
        printf ("Error occurred\n");
    }
    else {
        printf ("%d\n", x);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
# ./a.out
65
```